# Programmatically set properties to exclude from serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

Is it possible to programmatically set that you want to exclude a property from serialization?

Example:

- When de-serializing, I want to load up an ID field
- When serializing, I want to NOT output the ID field

Comment: For a better answer, suggest you clarify your serialization mechanism - e.g. XML serialization, Data Contract Serialization, etc

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I believe there are three options here:

1. Use [XmlIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) attribute. The downside is that you need to know in advance which properties you want the xmlserializer to ignore.
2. Implement the [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) interface. This gives you complete control on the output of XML, but you need to implement the read/write methods yourself.
3. Implement the [ICustomTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.aspx) interface. I believe this will make your solution to work no matter what type of serialization you choose, but it is probably the lengthiest solution of all.

Answer (score 18):

It depends on serialization type. Here full example for doing this with BinaryFormatter:

You may use [OnDeserializedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx):

```
[Serializable]
class SerializableEntity
{
  [OnDeserialized]
  private void OnDeserialized()
  {
    id = RetrieveId();
  }

  private int RetrievId() {}

  [NonSerialized]
  private int id;
}
```

And there is another way to do this using [IDeserializationCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ideserializationcallback.aspx):

```
[Serializable]
class SerializableEntity: IDeserializationCallback 
{
  void IDeserializationCallback.OnDeserialization(Object sender) 
  {
    id = RetrieveId();
  }

  private int RetrievId() {}

  [NonSerialized]
  private int id;
}
```

Also you may read great Jeffrey Richter's article about serialization: [part 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985952.aspx) and [part 2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb985956.aspx).

Comment: The first one gave me trouble but the second one works perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

If you are serializing to XML, you can use [XMLIgnore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute(v=VS.71).aspx)

As in:

```
class SomeClass
{
  [XmlIgnore] int someID;
  public string someString;
}
```

Comment: ... and the NonSerialized attribute if you're using the BinaryFormatter or SoapFormatter.

Answer (score 5):

An old post, but I found ShouldSerialize pattern
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53b8022e%28VS.71%29.aspx That is really HELPFUL!!!

Comment: Probably the most simple and useful solution to take absolute control about serializing or not properties at runtime! I used to use it when I was developing user controls in windows forms.

Comment: and it probably works only in windows forms designer serialization case.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include field during serialization but ignore it during deserialization then you can use [OnDeserializedAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx) to run a method which will set default value for ID field.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using XML serialization, use the `[XmlIgnore]` attribute. Otherwise, how to ignore a particular property is defined by the serializer itself.

Answer (score 0):

The NonSerializedAttribute attribute.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx