# prevent object memebers from appearing in placeholders of web service

Tags: c#, asmx

I'm writing a web service and have passed an object which is showing up as

```
      <OfferDetail>
        <OfferID>long</OfferID>
        <InterestID>long</InterestID>
        <RangeValue>string</RangeValue>
        <Score>string</Score>
        <Importance>string</Importance>
        <Range>string</Range>
        <ImportanceByOtherUser>string</ImportanceByOtherUser>
        <RangeByOtherUser>string</RangeByOtherUser>
      </OfferDetail>
```

in the web service placeholder but i don't want the

```
 <ImportanceByOtherUser>string</ImportanceByOtherUser>
 <RangeByOtherUser>string</RangeByOtherUser>
```

to be there is the place holders.
Note: i can't remove them from the object

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "placeholders"? Do you mean the help page you get when you browse to the web service? Is this an ASMX service or a WCF service?

Comment: @JohnSaunders ys dat is it...

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inherited properties do not appear in soap sample on asmx file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875642/inherited-properties-do-not-appear-in-soap-sample-on-asmx-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a known bug.

```
http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WsdlHelpGenerator/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=412
```

download the file and add the following in the web config

```
    <webServices>
 <wsdlHelpGenerator href="CustomWsdlHelpGenerator.aspx"/>
</webServices>
```

`Href` should point to the file downloaded in your the project

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WCF, then you probably have the `DataContractAttribute` applied to the object whose data you're returning via the service. If this is a service definition (which I doubt, but you didn't post any C# code), then you'll want to get rid of the `OperationContractAttribute` that's decorating these properties. But I believe it's the latter rather than the former—so I'd look for `DataContractAttribute`s first.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering *why ?*.

Are this members for internal web service usage, or private data? I've seen sometimes some developers publishing directly the ORM object through the web service. While it may works, It's often a bad idea as you don't want to expose the whole object, but only a subset of the object, or even a composition of several objects (customer's main detail + last orders in the month for example).

Thus I strongly advise you to refactor your code. You should create some DTO objects that are dedicated to data output of your web service, and command objects for input.

You specified you can't change the object, but what about adding another layer?

Answer (score 0):

What type of webservice are you using?  Depending on this you can use attributes like `XmlIgnore`, `NonSerialized`, `IgnoreDataMember` etc.

See

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791946/how-can-i-ignore-a-property-when-serializing-using-the-datacontractserializer)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017194/programmatically-set-properties-to-exclude-from-serialization)