# Serialize nested classes in c# : Specify what elements to be serialized

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, serialization, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a complex data model which i want to serialize. Each class has multiple navigation properties. How do I set which path of navigation need to be followed. I added a View Model specifying only the classes I need to serialize but it throws the following error

> There was an error reflecting type

I have also tried applying serialization by directly calling the parent class.

Expected Output

```
<LsystemFamily>Family Name
   <Lsystem>System Name1
      <Option>Option1
         <OptionValue> OptionValue1
           <SetValue>
               Val 1.1
               Val 1.2
           </SetValue>
         </optionValue>
         <OptionValue>OptionValue 2
           <SetValue>
               Val 2.1
               Val 2.2
           </SetValue>
         </optionValue>
       </Option>
       <Option> Option 2
         .....
       </Option>
    </Lsystem>
    <Lsystem> Lsystem 2
      ....
    </Lsystem>
</Lsystemfamily>
```

**XML Serialize function**

```
var model = new export_test
   {
     Lsystem = new List<Lsystem>(),
     Option = new List<Option>(),
     OptionValue = new List<OptionValue>(),
     SetValue = new List<SetValue>()
   };
model.LsystemFamily = db.LsystemFamily.FirstOrDefault(x => x.LsystemFamilyID != 0);
model.Lsystem = db.Lsystem.Where(x => x.LsystemFamilyID == model.LsystemFamily.LsystemFamilyID).ToList();
foreach (var item in model.Lsystem)
    model.Option = db.Option.Where(x => x.LsystemID == item.LsystemID).ToList();
foreach (var item in model.Option)
    model.OptionValue = db.OptionValue.Where(x => x.OptionID == item.OptionID).ToList();
foreach (var item in model.OptionValue)
    model.SetValue = db.SetValue.Where(x => x.OptionValueID == item.OptionValueID).ToList();

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(export_test));
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TEDALS-Ver01.4\xml\newxml.xml");
serializer.Serialize(writer.BaseStream, model);
```

**ViewModel**

```
    public virtual LsystemFamily LsystemFamily { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Lsystem> Lsystem {get;set;}
    public virtual List<Option> Option { get; set; }
    public virtual List<OptionValue> OptionValue { get; set; }
    public virtual List<SetValue> SetValue { get; set; }
```

But in the class definition of all the above classes there are navigation properties defined. How should I specify which property should be taken for serialization. I have many properties and Navigation for the above classes. What should be done if I do not want all the properties to be displayed in the XML file.

For instance `Class OptionValue` has properties :

- Name
- ID
- CreatedBy
- CreatedOn...
- ICollection
- ICollection

But in the XML i only want the name, ICollection.

Should I create serializable ViewModel classes for each model classes?

Comment: Please check out this how to exclude properties on serialisation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017194/programmatically-set-properties-to-exclude-from-serialization

Comment: @Raider: Should I add it in the model class or i should create viewmodels and add the properties. ?

Comment: You need to put it on the class property you want to exclude

Comment: I can do it all in the model class right?  I do not have to create ViewModels to do that. I should write a constructor in the model class as well?

Comment: To be very honest I haven't tried it. You need to do little bit experiment.

Comment: All this i was experimenting with ViewModels. Now maybe I do it with models :) i will giv it a  try

Comment: @Vini You might need to change how `Family Name` is serialized. I thought that, even though your expected output is valid XML, the XmlSerializer had issues with a textnode sibling to other elements. Someone correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: the xml is just a sample. I had it write it. So in the real scene it will nt b d way it is. I knw the attribute name will enclose the attribute value. Too much to type then.

Comment: np. I just checked and i was wrong. When you have a property annotated with [XmlTextAttribute] the `Family Name` would be placed within that Property.